# Network Docker-Compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a docker-compose with a bridge network called `mdb_default`, where I have a database.

I want to deploy another docker-compose that connects to that network that already exists, but I don't know how to define it in the docker-compose.
My file is:

```
supeset:
    container_name: superset
    build: .
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - mariadb
    environment:
      MAPBOX_API_KEY: 'pk.eyJ1IjoiamFta2lsbHM1IiwiYSI6ImNrd293aDJyZjA3MGQyd3AzdTJpeXp0dTAifQ.w96chqjB6Nv3PW6_lpQVHQ'
    ports:
      - 8000:8088
    volumes:
      - ./superset-data:/var/lib/mysql
    networks:
      - mdb_defatult
networks:
  mdb_dafault:
    driver: bridge
```

What do I need to do to connect to this existing network?

The network information is that I want to connect both is:

```
        "Name": "mdb_default",
        "Id": "2c69ba9fb42c1d9ca6142ae49c403d44bae5e297b78f4339c4782d3658f3d49c",
        "Created": "2022-05-17T14:17:47.935473033Z",
        "Scope": "local",
        "Driver": "bridge",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": null,
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "172.20.0.0/16",
                    "Gateway": "172.20.0.1"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described here: https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/#use-a-pre-existing-network

Try:

```
supeset:
    container_name: superset
    build: .
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - mariadb
    environment:
      MAPBOX_API_KEY: 'pk.eyJ1IjoiamFta2lsbHM1IiwiYSI6ImNrd293aDJyZjA3MGQyd3AzdTJpeXp0dTAifQ.w96chqjB6Nv3PW6_lpQVHQ'
    ports:
      - 8000:8088
    volumes:
      - ./superset-data:/var/lib/mysql
    networks:
      - mdb
networks:
  mdb:
    external:
      name: mdb_default
```

Answer (score 0):

You can declare an `external` network in the compose file and then have each service attach itself to that. Here's the documentation for the flag and another article that shows it in practice a bit more:

- https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/#use-a-pre-existing-network
- https://poopcode.com/join-to-an-existing-network-from-a-docker-container-in-docker-compose/